# how to dynamically download of zip file without taking physical memory in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, zip, download

i have one zip file(130 MB size). i need to download that,before that i need to append dynamic new text file in that zip, due to that original source of the zip file not be affect. With no duplicate of zip file create in server.

i need to download that dynamic zip file without taking any physical memory in SERVLET.

please help me how to do in java

orginal file
(C:\user\sample.zip)
text file
(c:\temp\userinfo.txt)

download file(C:\user\sample.zip + c:\temp\userinfo.txt) new zip file

Comment: Let me see if I understand this, are you saying you need to download a zip file and you cannot either store it in memory or disk in your server? Because if that's what you're a suggesting those are quite paradoxical requirements.

Comment: not like that, users downloading in the server. While downloading i need to dynamically append new file in that zip. This dynamic process may not to create any memory in server. Also original source (before append new file) could be affect in the server.